# admin-ajax.php 400 bad request - whats wrong with my code?

Tags: php, javascript, code

I'm getting a 400 bad request from admin-ajax.php & warnings from pagespeed insights tell me it's an issue.

Can you see any obvious issues in the code in our admin-ajax.php file?

```
<?php
/**
 * WordPress Ajax Process Execution
 *
 * @package WordPress
 * @subpackage Administration
 *
 * @link https://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins
 */

/**
 * Executing Ajax process.
 *
 * @since 2.1.0
 */
define( 'DOING_AJAX', true );
if ( ! defined( 'WP_ADMIN' ) ) {
    define( 'WP_ADMIN', true );
}

/** Load WordPress Bootstrap */
require_once( dirname( dirname( __FILE__ ) ) . '/wp-load.php' );

/** Allow for cross-domain requests (from the front end). */
send_origin_headers();

// Require an action parameter
if ( empty( $_REQUEST['action'] ) )
    wp_die( '0', 400 );

/** Load WordPress Administration APIs */
require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/admin.php' );

/** Load Ajax Handlers for WordPress Core */
require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/ajax-actions.php' );

@header( 'Content-Type: text/html; charset=' . get_option( 'blog_charset' ) );
@header( 'X-Robots-Tag: noindex' );

send_nosniff_header();
nocache_headers();

/** This action is documented in wp-admin/admin.php */
do_action( 'admin_init' );

$core_actions_get = array(
    'fetch-list', 'ajax-tag-search', 'wp-compression-test', 'imgedit-preview', 'oembed-cache',
    'autocomplete-user', 'dashboard-widgets', 'logged-in',
);

$core_actions_post = array(
    'oembed-cache', 'image-editor', 'delete-comment', 'delete-tag', 'delete-link',
    'delete-meta', 'delete-post', 'trash-post', 'untrash-post', 'delete-page', 'dim-comment',
    'add-link-category', 'add-tag', 'get-tagcloud', 'get-comments', 'replyto-comment',
    'edit-comment', 'add-menu-item', 'add-meta', 'add-user', 'closed-postboxes',
    'hidden-columns', 'update-welcome-panel', 'menu-get-metabox', 'wp-link-ajax',
    'menu-locations-save', 'menu-quick-search', 'meta-box-order', 'get-permalink',
    'sample-permalink', 'inline-save', 'inline-save-tax', 'find_posts', 'widgets-order',
    'save-widget', 'delete-inactive-widgets', 'set-post-thumbnail', 'date_format', 'time_format',
    'wp-remove-post-lock', 'dismiss-wp-pointer', 'upload-attachment', 'get-attachment',
    'query-attachments', 'save-attachment', 'save-attachment-compat', 'send-link-to-editor',
    'send-attachment-to-editor', 'save-attachment-order', 'heartbeat', 'get-revision-diffs',
    'save-user-color-scheme', 'update-widget', 'query-themes', 'parse-embed', 'set-attachment-thumbnail',
    'parse-media-shortcode', 'destroy-sessions', 'install-plugin', 'update-plugin', 'crop-image',
    'generate-password', 'save-wporg-username', 'delete-plugin', 'search-plugins',
    'search-install-plugins', 'activate-plugin', 'update-theme', 'delete-theme', 'install-theme',
    'get-post-thumbnail-html', 'get-community-events', 'edit-theme-plugin-file',
    'wp-privacy-export-personal-data',
    'wp-privacy-erase-personal-data',
);

// Deprecated
$core_actions_post_deprecated = array( 'wp-fullscreen-save-post', 'press-this-save-post', 'press-this-add-category' );
$core_actions_post = array_merge( $core_actions_post, $core_actions_post_deprecated );

// Register core Ajax calls.
if ( ! empty( $_GET['action'] ) && in_array( $_GET['action'], $core_actions_get ) )
    add_action( 'wp_ajax_' . $_GET['action'], 'wp_ajax_' . str_replace( '-', '_', $_GET['action'] ), 1 );

if ( ! empty( $_POST['action'] ) && in_array( $_POST['action'], $core_actions_post ) )
    add_action( 'wp_ajax_' . $_POST['action'], 'wp_ajax_' . str_replace( '-', '_', $_POST['action'] ), 1 );

add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_heartbeat', 'wp_ajax_nopriv_heartbeat', 1 );

if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
    // If no action is registered, return a Bad Request response.
    if ( ! has_action( 'wp_ajax_' . $_REQUEST['action'] ) ) {
        wp_die( '0', 400 );
    }

    /**
     * Fires authenticated Ajax actions for logged-in users.
     *
     * The dynamic portion of the hook name, `$_REQUEST['action']`,
     * refers to the name of the Ajax action callback being fired.
     *
     * @since 2.1.0
     */
    do_action( 'wp_ajax_' . $_REQUEST['action'] );
} else {
    // If no action is registered, return a Bad Request response.
    if ( ! has_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_' . $_REQUEST['action'] ) ) {
        wp_die( '0', 400 );
    }

    /**
     * Fires non-authenticated Ajax actions for logged-out users.
     *
     * The dynamic portion of the hook name, `$_REQUEST['action']`,
     * refers to the name of the Ajax action callback being fired.
     *
     * @since 2.8.0
     */
    do_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_' . $_REQUEST['action'] );
}
// Default status
wp_die( '0' );
```

By clicking inspect element, then refreshing with the network tab open, then clicking initiator i can see a red x next to the code which seems to be causing the problem. What is the issue with that ?

Code here:

```
;!function() {
var t, e, n, o = 0, u = function(t, e) {
    return "function" != typeof t || t.replaced ? t : (e.replaced = !0,
    e)
};
if ("undefined" != typeof CustomEvent && "function" == typeof window.dispatchEvent) {
    var r = function(t) {
        try {
            if ("object" == typeof t && (t = JSON.stringify(t)),
            "string" == typeof t)
                return window.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent("lprequeststart",{
                    detail: {
                        data: t,
                        requestID: ++o
                    }
                })),
                o
        } catch (t) {}
    }
      , s = function(t) {
        try {
            window.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent("lprequestend",{
                detail: t
            }))
        } catch (t) {}
    };
    "undefined" != typeof XMLHttpRequest && XMLHttpRequest.prototype && XMLHttpRequest.prototype.send && (XMLHttpRequest.prototype.send = u(XMLHttpRequest.prototype.send, (n = XMLHttpRequest.prototype.send,
    function(t) {
        var e = this
          , o = r(t);
        return o && e.addEventListener("loadend", function() {
            s({
                requestID: o,
                statusCode: e.status
            })
        }),
        n.apply(e, arguments) **THIS IS WHERE THE RED X SUGGESTS AN ISSUE**
    }
    ))),
    "function" == typeof fetch && (fetch = u(fetch, (e = fetch,
    function(t, n) {
        var o = r(n)
          , u = e.apply(this, arguments);
        if (o) {
            var c = function(t) {
                s({
                    requestID: o,
                    statusCode: t && t.status
                })
            };
            u.then(c).catch(c)
        }
        return u
    }
    )));
    var c = function(t) {
        return u(t, function() {
            try {
                this.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent("lpsubmit"))
            } catch (t) {}
            return t.apply(this, arguments)
        })
    }
      , i = function() {
        if (document && document.forms && document.forms.length > 0)
            for (var t = 0; t < document.forms.length; ++t)
                document.forms[t].submit = c(document.forms[t].submit)
    };
    document && "interactive" === document.readyState || "complete" === document.readyState ? i() : window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", i, !0),
    Document.prototype.createElement = u(Document.prototype.createElement, (t = Document.prototype.createElement,
    function() {
        var e = t.apply(this, arguments);
        return e && "FORM" === e.nodeName && e.submit && (e.submit = c(e.submit)),
        e
    }
    ))
}
```

}

[image]

Comment: Did you edit the Core admin-ajax.php? I'm hoping you didn't, never change WP core files! The problem isn't in that file. Another app/plugin/theme on your website is calling it incorrectly. Try to debug WP. Are you seeing the error always? When are you seeing the error. What is the WP version? You have to include way more info for us to help you.

Comment: No i just assumed the issue is with that file. Wordpress 4.9.6. admin-ajax.php is 400 bad request every time & doubles website load time.

Comment: You can try disabling all plugins and theme back to default. Check if problem is gone, then activate everything one by one untill the problem starts. Then you'll know what is causing it.

Comment: Disabled all of the plugins, cleared cache etc & still get the bad 400 request on admin-ajax.php

Comment: And did you try a default WP theme?

Comment: I don't know how to change my theme to default & worry i'll break the website if i try.

Comment: I managed to fix this using a combination of autoptimize, fastest cache premium which i already had but adding the plugin JCH optimize. This resulted in 23 http requests rather than 15 but it loads in half the time because the admin-ajax.php request is no longer triggering. It also didn't break my drop down menus like all of my attempts with Autoptimize & Fastest cache alone did.

Comment: Actual this fix just stops the bad http request but it still shows when you "inspect element" and also breaks my responsive menu plugin which is the only way people can navigate the website on mobile.

Comment: That's because you're not fixing the problem. Check all your log files, you have to get to the root of the problem. Installing plugins and hoping it fixes your ajax problem is not the way to go.

Comment: In our error logs inside cpanel it's just blank so it' no help.

Comment: Try the `wp_debug`, google it for more info.

Comment: Are you using this on the front-end? If so, please [enqueue admin-ajax](https://wpza.net/wordpress-setup/how-to-update-wordpress-posts-with-ajax-on-the-front-end/) as such to load it in the front-end.

Answer (score 0):

Using chrome dev tools i found the file which was creating the http request.

This file was theme.min.js, i looked at the file & could see "porto_refresh_cart_fragments" though the file was minified so I didn't know what to remove.

After using a website to unminify the file it was clearer what i needed to remove so i stripped the code from the file because we don't have a cart on the website so it's obsolete.

The http request for admin-ajax.php from porto_refresh_cart_fragment is now fixed. I just thought i'd put this information here for future reference in case anyone else get the same issue, though this only worked because we didn't have a cart, it may help someone.